# JavaFX 2.x: Set stops for XY LineChart

Tags: javafx-2, linechart

By left mouse click anywhere on the chart, plotted line can be moved (dragged) left / right

Here is the code

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis; 
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; 
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane; 

public class XYMove extends Application {

BorderPane pane; 
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series(); 

SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(); 
SimpleDoubleProperty rectX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(); 
SimpleDoubleProperty rectY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(); 

@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) { 

final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(4, 16, 1); 
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0005); 

xAxis.setAnimated(false);
yAxis.setAnimated(false);

yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) { 

@Override 
public String toString(Number object) { 
    return String.format("%7.5f", object); 
} 
}); 

final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis); 

lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false); 
lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false); 
lineChart.setAnimated(false); 
lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.53185)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.532235)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 0.53234)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 0.538765)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 0.53442)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 0.534658)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 0.53023)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 0.53001)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 0.53589)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 0.53476));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 0.53023)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 0.53001)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(13, 0.53589)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(14, 0.53476)); 

pane = new BorderPane(); 
pane.setCenter(lineChart); 
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600); 
lineChart.getData().addAll(series1); 

stage.setScene(scene);         

scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler); 
scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler); 
stage.show();
} 

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 

@Override 
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) { 

if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {             
    rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX()); 
} 
else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED ||   mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) { 
    LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = (LineChart<Number, Number>) pane.getCenter(); 
    NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis(); 

    double Tgap = xAxis.getWidth()/(xAxis.getUpperBound() - xAxis.getLowerBound()); 
    double newXlower=xAxis.getLowerBound(), newXupper=xAxis.getUpperBound();             
    double Delta=0.3;

    if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
    if(rectinitX.get() < mouseEvent.getX()){    
        newXlower=xAxis.getLowerBound()-Delta;
        newXupper=xAxis.getUpperBound()-Delta;
    }
else if(rectinitX.get() > mouseEvent.getX()){    
        newXlower=xAxis.getLowerBound()+Delta;
        newXupper=xAxis.getUpperBound()+Delta;
    }    
    xAxis.setLowerBound( newXlower ); 
    xAxis.setUpperBound( newXupper );                        
    }                                        
    rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());                                 
 } 
 } 
 }; 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

And now to my question: is there a way to modify this code so to stop this left / right move when X value is == 0 ( no need to step in negative X values) and X == end value for NumberAxis? (in this case == 16).

```
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(4, 16, 1);
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Found a good solution by adding 
if(rectinitX.get() < mouseEvent.getX()&& newXlower >= 0) and
else if(rectinitX.get() > mouseEvent.getX()&& newXupper <= 16)

Question closed